# soft question about a sequence of random variables that a.s. converges

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Suppose we have a sequence $(X_n)$ of random variables. Let $X_n \to X $ a.s. for $n \to \infty$ Does common results like $\liminf X_n = \limsup X_n = \lim X_n =X $ hold? Furthermore, are there any exceptions to take care of or can we adapt every result to real number sequences?

Comment: The a.s. convergence roughly means that there exists a set with null measure such that, outside this set, the convergence is simple. In particular, your result (equality for liminf/limsup) holds on the complementary of the previous set.

Comment: but for example let $X_n$ a non negative supermartingale with canonical filtration. And $X_n \to X$ a.s. Then $\liminf X_n = \limsup X_n = \lim X_n = X$ a.s. should hold, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a sequence of real valued random variables you can use the same results like for real numbers. A.s. convergence mean $$P\left(\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) = \lim_{n\to\infty} X_n(\omega)\right) = 1$$

But for each $\omega$ it holds that $X(\omega)$ resp. $X_n(\omega)$ are real numbers so you can work with them as usual.

Comment: check my comment above. Would this hold also for non real $ X_n $? Good answer though!

Comment: I just notice martingales are real valued.., so the answer to my above question is yes!